# How to get ContentVersion Public Link?

Tags: apex, soql, content

I am trying to get `ContentVersion` i.e Files public link URL of File Attached to any object which I need to pass in XML. So that it is visible to anyone without logging to salesforce(Want public link URL of File Attached to any object.)

What I have tried so far:

```
        cdlist = new List<ContentDocumentLink>([Select ContentDocumentID,LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId IN: pulicationIdsSet]);

        Map<Id,Id> linkedDocsMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
        for(ContentDocumentLink cl:cdlist){
            linkedDocsMap.put(cl.ContentDocumentID,cl.LinkedEntityId);
        }
        cvlist = new List<ContentVersion>([Select Id,ContentDocumentId,title FROM ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId in:linkedDocsMap.keySet() order by CreatedDate DESC]);       

        contentVerMap = new Map<ID, List<ContentVersion>>();
        for(ContentVersion file : cvlist){
            Id linkId = linkedDocsMap.get(file.ContentDocumentId);
            if(!contentVerMap.containsKey(linkId))
                contentVerMap.put(linkedDocsMap.get(file.ContentDocumentId),new List<ContentVersion>());
            contentVerMap.get(linkId).add(file);
        }
```

Comment: This is the ***Salesforce*** Stack Exchange. You don't have to tell us your question is about Salesforce. If it weren't, it would be off topic.

Comment: the link is the same as when you click Download button on the file in the standard UI (it is a servlet invocation)

Answer (score 5):

I'm still trying to figure this out myself, but I believe what you are looking for is the DistributionPublicUrl field on the ContentDistribution object. I think the query would be something like:

```
select DistributionPublicUrl from ContentDistribution where ContentDocumentId = :file.ContentDocumentId
```

It looks like the ContentDistribution record is what gets created when you generate a public link to a file.